# Not able to visualize a loaded data

Tags: load, xtk

I just start to test xtk, and no problem with the first sample of the cube. I now try to load an external data, but stored locally into my filesystem (just download skull sample of example 05) and put in the same directory of the html. I'm not able to see anything.
I've also run the tests and the visualization is ok but when I try to open one of test htmls, it isn't able to visualize the sample. Is there some problem of path? I really try to put myself in the most simple situation but I don't see anything.
I use Chrome, and when I check the demos, it is all ok.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the origin security check. If you open the Javascript Console, you would prolly see something like '403 error'..

To test locally, you have to start chrome with an argument '-allow-file-access-from-files' or you just run a webserver like 'python -m SimpleHTTPServer' in the directory of your html file and access then in the browser http://localhost:8000/

Here is some more information:

[Google Chrome --allow-file-access-from-files disabled for Chrome Beta 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270999/google-chrome-allow-file-access-from-files-disabled-for-chrome-beta-8)
http://robspangler.com/blog/jquery-load-doesnt-work-in-chrome/