# chrome turn off security toDataUrl

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Is it possible to turn off the Google security for toDataUrl
I have tried the following but without any luck.

Add the `–allow-file-access-from-files –disable-web-security` to *Chrome.exe* Windows 7 will not allow me to change it.
I have also try to type in the full path like:

```
source src=file:///E:/canvas_to_png/Chrome_ImF.mp4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can run chrome from the command line, and append your line above `--allow-file-access-from-files` I'm not sure where you got the part `-disable-web-security`

You can find more links to resources [right here on this stack question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270999/google-chrome-allow-file-access-from-files-disabled-for-chrome-beta-8)

But this should work appended to the end of the path on your desktop shortcut. I use it all the time actually.

Comment: i am not sure what i ' m doing wrong `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe--allow-file-access-from-files"` win7 problem with shortcut target box is not valid. ?

Comment: @Harvid right click on your desktop application go to the end of the Target field then add it there: it will look like this: `"path_to_your_chrome\chrome.exe" --allow-file-access-from-files` note that the `--allow-file` part is outside of the quotes.

Comment: it is so strange sem result,i have ever tried to run it like .bat `START C:\Users\Eyal\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files 
EXIT`

Comment: @Harvid you tried it with the `--allow-file-access-from-files` outside the quotes and with a space between it and the path? and you got the same result?

Comment: @Harvid no, no, no, like this: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --allow-file-access-from-files` do it just like that nothing else.

Comment: when i'm rightclicking on my shortcut and in target:`C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"--allow-file-access-from-files` windows still say target box is not valid, windows doesn't seems to like something after .exe

Comment: @Harvid have you checked to make sure that that is actually a valid path? That's not where my chrome install is actually located. Also your missing a space right here `"....chrome.exe"--allow-file-access-from-files` it should be: `"....chrome.exe" --allow-file-access-from-files`

Comment: Thank you very much, One small space make the difference, and now its works :)