# ng-view not working for my app

Tags: angularjs

app.js //this is my app.js file I've included another file containing the HeaderCtrlModule in it

```
var app = angular.module("BooKart",["ngRoute","HeaderCtrlModule"]);

app.config(function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider
.when("/books",{
 templateUrl: "views/book-list.html",
 controller: "BookListCtrl"
 })
 .when("/kart",{
 templateUrl: "views/kart-list.html"
 })
 .otherwise({
  redirectTo: "/books"
 })
 });
```

kart-list.html //this loads the kart view

```
<div>
This is Kart view.
</div>
```

book-list.html// this loads the booklist view

```
<div id="bookListWrapper">
<form role="form">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search here...">
</div>
</form>
<br/>
<ul class="list-unstyled">
<li class="book" ng-repeat="book in books"
style="background: white url('imgs/{{book.imgUrl}}') no-repeat">
<div class="book-details clearfix">
<h3>{{book.name}}</h3>
<p>{{book.price}}</p>
<ul class="list-unstyled list-inline">
<li>Rating: {{book.rating}}</li>
<li>Binding: {{book.binding}}</li>
<li>Publisher: {{book.publisher}}</li>
<li>Released: {{book.releaseDate}}</li>
</ul>
<p>{{book.details}}</p>
<button class="btn btn-info pull-right" ng-click="addToKart(book)">Add to 
Kart</button>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en" ng-app="BooKart">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Welcome to BooKart</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <script src="lib/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers/app.js"></script>

  <script src="js/controllers/HeaderCtrl.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <div id="header-wrapper" ng-controller="HeaderCtrl">
      <span class="logo pull-left">{{appDetails.title}}</span>
      <span class="tagline pull-left">{{appDetails.tagline}}</span>
  <div class="nav-wrapper pull-left">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills">
              <li class="active"><a href="#!/books">Books</a></li>
              <li><a href="#!/kart">Kart</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div ng-view>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

HeaderCtrl.js

```
angular.module("HeaderCtrlModule",[])

.controller("HeaderCtrl",["$scope",function($scope)
{

$scope.appDetails = {};
$scope.appDetails.title = "BooKart";
$scope.appDetails.tagline = "We have 1 Million Books for you";

}])

.controller("BookListCtrl",["$scope","$http",function($scope,$http){
{

$scope.books = [
    {
        imgUrl: "adultery.jpeg",
        name: "Adultery",
        price: 205,
        rating: 4,
        binding: "Paperback",
        publisher: "Random House India",
        releaseDate: "12-08-2014",
        details: "Linda, in her thirties, begins to question the routine and 
predictability of her days. In everybodys eyes, she has a perfect life-happy 
marriage, children and a career. Yet what she feels is an eno... <a 
href='#'>View More<a>"
    },
    {
        imgUrl: "geronimo.jpeg",
        name: "Geronimo Stilton Spacemice#2 : You're Mine, Captain!",
        price: 168,
        rating: 5,
        binding: "Paperback",
        publisher: "Scholastic",
        releaseDate: "01-07-2014",
        details: "Geronimo Stilton meets outer space in this cosmically fun 
 spin-off series!Meet Geronimo StiltonixHe is a spacemouse - the Geronimo 
 Stilton of a parallel universe! He is captain of the spaceship Mou... View 
 More"
    },
    {
        imgUrl: "life-or-death.jpeg",
        name: "Life or Death",
        price: 339,
        rating: 4,
        binding: "Paperback",
        publisher: "Hachette India",
        releaseDate: "01-04-2014",
        details: "Why would a man escape from prison the day before he's due 
   to be released? Audie Palmer has spent a decade in prison for an armed 
  robbery in which four people died, including two of his gang. Five... View 
More"
    },
    {
        imgUrl: "playing.jpeg",
        name: "Playing It My Way : My Autobiography",
        price: 599,
        rating: 5,
        binding: "Hardcover",
        publisher: "Hodder & Stoughton",
        releaseDate: "01-08-2014",
        details: "I knew that if I agreed to write my story, I would have to 
be completely honest, as thats the way I have always played the game and 
that would mean talking about a number of things I have not addr... View 
More"
    },
    {
        imgUrl: "the-fault.jpeg",
        name: "The Fault in Our Stars",
        price: 227,
        rating: 4.5,
        binding: "Paperback",
        publisher: "Penguin Books Ltd",
        releaseDate: "25-01-2013",
        details: "Despite the tumor-shrinking medical miracle that has 
 bought her a few years, Hazel has never been anything but terminal, her 
 final chapter inscribed upon diagnosis. But when a gorgeous plot twist n... 
 View More"
    },
    {
        imgUrl: "wings-of-fire.jpeg",
        name: "Wings of Fire: An Autobiography",
        price: 124,
        rating: 5,
        binding: "Paperback",
        publisher: "Universities Press",
        releaseDate: "25-08-2000",
        details: "Wings of Fire traces the life and times of India's former 
 president A.P.J. Abdul Kalam. It gives a glimpse of his childhood as well 
 as his growth as India's Missile Man. Summary of the Book Wings... View 
 More"
    }


$scope.addToKart = function(book)
{
    console.log("add to kart: ", book);
}

}]);
```

I think the code looks fine I've also included #!/ rather #/ not sure why it is not working please some take a look at tell me what is wrong. I'm new to angular and there is no error in the console, so that also doesn't help. Thanks in advance. please do help me out

Comment: what is your question here??

Comment: the view wont change

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: it just has my header displayed and not the body as soon as it loads it should display the contents of book-list.html

Comment: nothing on the console it just wont work

Comment: are you sure view are inside `views` folder ?, and in your `BookListCtrl` controller there is no `.controller` ?

Comment: Yea thet're in the views folder, the mistake was i'd  written controller instead of .controller i fixed that but its still the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't use local server, Chrome doesn't load other html files in existing html. But, it will work in Firefox browser..

Try visual studio. Create a project in visual studio and run using it.

Comment: ill exceed the limit of characters If i post it

Comment: It works just fine in firefox. I mean can you please explain as to why it won't work in chrome

Comment: check the answer in the link for better understanding. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16251614/8090237

Comment: I actually am running it using a local server I'm using Xampp

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues in your code :

Remove extra `{` in your `BookListCtrl` function.

Correct your route, change it to : `href="#/kart"`

See this [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Gd3bqd6NcpZs2FlRVhnS?p=preview)

Your included scripts seems to be ok, and just a suggestion your module name is `BooKart`, not `BookKart`

Comment: I double checked the name it says BooKart, I've fixed the BookListCtrl as well it seems to work fine in firefox but not in chrome for some reason

Comment: @ShashankShankaranand: Try with inject `$locationProvider`, in your `route config` and set  `$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');`  after all routes