# AngularJS Route does not loading view

Tags: angularjs, routes

My project structure is looks like this:

[image: project structure]

I tried to make a single page application using [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WNfq.jpg) image. When **index.html** page will launch it will by default load **registration.html** in ng-view. But when **index.html** loads it does not load the **registration.html** as ng-view as expected.

And my files for **index.html**,**main.css** and **mainAppRouter.js** are below:

```js
//mainAppRouter.js

(function () {
    var myModule = angular.module('studentInfo', ['ngRoute']);
    myModule.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/registration', {
                templateUrl : '../views/registration.html',
                controller: 'regController'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/registration'
            });
        
        console.log("checking");
    });

    myModule.controller('regController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.message = 'This is Add new order screen';
        console.log("checking");
    });

});
```

```css
/*man.css*/

.studentInfo{
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.navbar{
    padding: 1em;
}

.navbar-brand {
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<!--index.html-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="studentInfo">

<head>
    <script src="lib/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/js/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/js/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="app/route/mainAppRouter.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/css/bootstrap-theme.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/css/main.css" />
    <title>A demo Angular JS app</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> <span><img src="app/images/people.png"/></span> Student Info </a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav nav-pills navbar-right" data-ng-controller="NavbarController">
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#/registration">Registration</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#/student">Student Details</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" data-ng-controller="regController">
            <h1>Student Info</h1>
        </div>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

All my codes are in this [github repo](https://github.com/PialKanti/StudentInfo)

What should i do to correct my problem?

Comment: what dispalyed in console?

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand. Why anything will be displayed in console?

Comment: I mean do you have any error that displaying in console.

Comment: no error. It does not load anything in ng-view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is because you have not specified any controller for your ng-view and also you have to set your base URL correctly.

```
 $routeProvider
            .when('/registration', {
              templateUrl :'http://localhost/StudentInfo/app/views/registration.html',
                controller: 'regController'
            })
```

And remove the controller tag from HTML.Your controller tag was outside the scope of ng-view.

```
  <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" >
            <h1>Student Info</h1>
        </div>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
```

And there is a syntax error in your controller as well

```
myModule.controller('regController', function ($scope){
    $scope.message = 'This is Add new order screen';
})
```

**UPDATED ANSWER:** Another reason why this does not work is that you are running your example off the file system (using the file:// protocol) and many browsers (Chrome, Opera) restricts XHR calls when using the file:// protocol. AngularJS templates are downloaded via XHR and this, combined with the usage of the file:// protocol results in the error you are getting.

For more details: [Couldn't load template using templateUrl in Angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16251420/couldnt-load-template-using-templateurl-in-angularjs)

Comment: Can you put a console inside your regController and check if the controller is loading.

Comment: I have updated my answer but still you seem to be missing a module. That is why injection module error is coming

Comment: I have correct the error. angular.js and angular-route.js were not in same version. But i have tried to console.log inside controller looks like controller is not loading.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146939/discussion-between-vivz-and-pial-kanti).