# How to use ui-sref in ui-router AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-components

i have file index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .navbar { border-radius:0; }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="./node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="./node_modules/angular-ui-bootstrap/dist/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
    <script src="./node_modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/js/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="nav-module">
    <a ui-view="home" ui-sref="home" ui-sref-active="active">home</a>
    <a ui-view="about" ui-sref="about" ui-sref-active="active">about</a>
        <ui-view>
        </ui-view>

</body>
</html>
```

and file app.js:

```
var app = angular.module("nav-module", ["ui.router",'ui.bootstrap']);
app.component('navComponent',{
    templateUrl: './navbar.component.html'
});
app.config(['$stateProvider',
'$urlRouterProvider',function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('/home',{
        name: 'home page',
        url:'/home',
        template: '<h3>hello world!</h3>'
    })
    .state('/about',{
        url:'/about',
        component: 'navComponent'
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
}]);
```

and nav-bar.component.html:

```
<h1>nav bar</h1>
```

but i can't click to  tag to run page, and when i change /about in URL, the console show error:

> Failed to load template: ./navbar.component.html

i dont know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're missing the templateurl location or file name as you mention that your
templateUrl:'./navbar.component.html' but your file name is nav-bar.component.html.

1. First remove templateUrl & check it by using template: `<h1>nav bar</h1>` in component.
2. If it's OK,then your error is for just missing the templateUrl refrence or the file name.
3. Then fix this by using ../app/navtemplateurl.html and file name is navtemplateurl.html which is inside the app folder.

Adding 'ui.bootstrap.tpls' in your module can also solve this problem

**Update**:  ust change the angularui router refrence from index file to `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.0-rc.1/angular-ui-router.js"></script>` as component templates in ui-router are not supported in v0.4.2 or earlier.
You also need to update this.

[image]

Comment: yep, same problem

Comment: i removed "/" on the state, and ui-route is working. But it also can not solve load template problem

Comment: Is it ok now ? I run it on my local machine and it's completely OK

Comment: I think I have the same problem as that link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16251420/couldnt-load-template-using-templateurl-in-angularjs. but when i run it in server, it showing same problem

Comment: Try using <base href=" /" /> in the top of head section in index file

Comment: i tried it in firefox and it is working. thank you so much for your help!