# Read JSON from local disk using browser

Tags: javascript, json, html, local-storage

I am working on a content management project where from a tool we generate html/js/css
and image files. The data we store in JSON format.

Now, I want to play the contents using browser without any server, i checked some threads
and it suggests that it may be possible using file:// protocol, I want to check if there 
is any limitation if I am not using any server. Or it is not possible to omit http server..

The other thing is that, I can't use concept of local storage because my data size is huge and in HTML5 the max size supported is 10 MB my requirement is approx 25 MB.

Please suggest.

Thanks.

Comment: Just have to allow the XMLHttpRequest to work off the file protocol.

Comment: How can i allow the xmlhttprequest , is there any specific settings for that

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Chrome --allow-file-access-from-files disabled for Chrome Beta 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270999/google-chrome-allow-file-access-from-files-disabled-for-chrome-beta-8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like an odd thing to do for a CMS, no? You can use the `readfile` API but you're limiting yourself to IE10+: http://caniuse.com/filereader

Edit, maybe should've been a comment but... If the data is only on clients computer, who can read the content of the CMS? Or are you creating 10MB+ files on every users computer?

Comment: Because i generate static html contents from my tool and put all in a folder and play contents in PC using usb .. so this is more of a offline application which is customizable for every user..

Comment: Ah ok, cool. If the users have modern browsers it can be done