# Webpage-text translation on client-side (without internet connectivity)

Tags: javascript, php, static-libraries, language-translation

I need a web-application to be translated from English to Portuguese.
Since the servers on which this application runs have no internet access, is there a way to achieve this without using a 3rd Party API. Is there a JS Library that can translate from say Language A to Language B on the client side ?

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely use Java Script for that.

The library well known for translations is the [i18next](http://i18next.com/)

You can integrate with jQuery, but I strongly recommend you using something like AngularJS or Mustache for customise your template.

If you choose use [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) you can have a different JSON file with your expressions, and depending on the language you are navigating, loads a different JSON file, like:

en.json, es.json, pt.json

You can use JS Cookies for saving the language as same you would do with any backend language.

[Mustache](https://mustache.github.io/) is used to create templates front-side with double brackets {{custom_text}}. AngularJS uses the same idea.

The only issue if you want to use AJAX. Read more about [Google Chrome --allow-file-access-from-files disabled for Chrome Beta 8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4270999/3415716)

Comment: Seems like this can help, but this requires additional configurations as appears from the samples and documentation. Do we have an option like, Everything on page in Language A gets Converted to Language B (So that only input I need to provide is "from" and "to") , Do we have something as simple as that ?

Comment: @sainiankit are you looking for an automatic service without using internet? I believe it'll be a little hard. To translate with JS, you can use all content of your app as variables. So each language has their group of variables as a JavaScript Object (or json file as I suggested). In this case, would have an English and a Spanish file/object. For each language the user choose, you'll load their language file/object. Does it work for you? Don't need much setting.

Comment: Check this example using Mustache.js http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-the-mustache-template-library--net-14590