# XMLHTTPRequest accepted by Mozilla rejected in other browsers

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I know little of Javascript but have managed to assemble a code for an ajax request on my web site but now find it is only working on Mozilla/Firefox. 
My code is:

```
    function ajaxFunction(char){
    var ajaxRequest;  
    try{
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
        if(this.status !==200){
        **alert("Error: Status '+this.status+' returned.");**
    }else{
            document.getElementById('directory').innerHTML=   ajaxRequest.responseText;
            }
        }
    }
    var namevalue=char
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "../directory pagtestAug.php?name="+namevalue, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}
```

I am also making use of:
     src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js">
(although I am not sure what this does - I am finding it difficult to find javascript tuition beyond the very basic)

The response is Error :Status'+this.status+' returned.

I have seen many posts on the 200 status but none on what to do if the server does not respond. Is there another code to use or a different one for each browser ?
Thank you for taking the trouble to read this (and reply, please)

Comment: Since you have jQuery, I suggest looking into [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: What are those `**`? Were you trying to comment that line?

Comment: Your quotes on the alert are mismatched. Change to "Error: Status " + this.status + " returned." to actually get a status code.

Comment: @ T.B Excellent comment. I amended the quotes and received an error code. With that information I was able to change a corrupt .js file and the pages are now correctly displayed in the 5 browsers mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

If by "works in Mozilla only" you mean it doesn't work in chrome, check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270999/google-chrome-allow-file-access-from-files-disabled-for-chrome-beta-8) and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome)

Basically you have to start chrome with the correct parameters to allow it to access local files.

Comment: I note you comment on Chrome and am looking into it, but as I said above the fault appears to have corrected without making these changes.